# Regex matches but sed fails replace

Tags: regex, sed

I am having a tricky regex issue

I have the string like below

```
some_Name   _  _Bday Date Comm.txt
```

And here is my regex to match the spaces and underscore

```
\_?\s\_?

Now when i try to replace the string using sed and the above regex

echo "some_Name   _  _Bday Date Comm.txt" | sed 's/\_?\s\_?/\_/g'
```

The output i want is

```
some_Name_Bday_Date_Comm.txt
```

Any ideas on how do i go about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a POSIX BRE regex engine with the `\_?\s\_?` pattern that matches a `_?`, a whitespace (if your `sed` supports `\s` shorthand) an a `_?` substring, i.e. the `?` are treated as literal question mark symbols.

You may use

```
sed -E 's/[[:space:]_]+/_/g'
sed 's/[[:space:]_]\{1,\}/_/g'
```

See [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/3cyDa3)

The `[[:space:]_]+` POSIX ERE pattern (enabled with `-E` option) will match one or more whitespace or underscore characters.

The POSIX ERE `+` quantifier can be written as `\{1,\}` in POSIX BRE. Also, if you use a GNU `sed`, you may use `\+` in the second `sed` command.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/\s(\s*_)*/_/g' file
```

This will replace a space followed by zero or more of the following: zero or more spaces followed by an underscore.